# TCP self connect is not simultaneous open?

Tags: networking, tcp, tcpdump

### To illustrate a TCP self connect example

- `nc -p 9987 127.0.0.1 9987`

### `tcpdump` captured the connection establishment

```
17:52:33.980137 IP 127.0.0.1.9987 > 127.0.0.1.9987: Flags [S], seq 4215993872, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 10050427 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:52:33.980162 IP 127.0.0.1.9987 > 127.0.0.1.9987: Flags [S.], seq 4215993872, ack 4215993873, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 10050427 ecr 10050427,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:52:33.980174 IP 127.0.0.1.9987 > 127.0.0.1.9987: Flags [.], ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 10050427 ecr 10050427], length 0
```

It was just like the normal TCP establishment, but the dst addr and src addr are the same.

### Recall the TCP simultaneous open [ref: TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 1, Figure 18.17 and Figure 18.18]

[image]
[image]

### Next, recall the TCP state transition diagram

[image]

For the self connect situation, the TCP state transition should be:

- send SYN to the dst, CLOSE -> SYN_SENT
- receive SYN (from self), send SYN+ACK to dst, SYN_SENT -> SYN_RCVD
- receive SYN+ACK (from self), SYN_RCVD -> ESTABLISHED

#### Question 1

The procedure is totally different(shown by tcpdump) between self connect and simultaneous open. Is there anything I missed?

#### Question 2

> receive SYN+ACK (from self), SYN_RCVD -> ESTABLISHED

This transition is not presented in the TCP state transition diagram. How to explain it?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a simultaneous open.  Simultaneous open is something that was theorized and written into the standard, but *never* happens in practice.

In a simultaneous open, the theory is that two hosts simultaneously (or near enough in that each end has not seen the initial SYN of the other side before attempting to open a connection) attempt to establish a connection, but with special conditions.

Host A opens from port X connecting to port Y on B.
Host B opens from port Y to port X on A.

In this case, you will see what appears to be a four way handshake.  If you'd like to prove to yourself that this works, you can use Scapy to try it out.  [Here is a Scapy script that you can run on a host](https://github.com/dhoelzer/AuditcastsScripts/blob/master/Scapy/4whs.py).  *You must use iptables to disabled outbound RST packets from the host or it will fail*

If you run that script and then connect from any other client host, you will see a four way handshake in action!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am clear about the simultaneous open now, but still confused about _self connect_, how to explain the establishment of self-connect TCP?

Comment: Self-connect isn't any different than connecting to another host.  The stack behaves in precisely the same way.  The only "difference" is that the "remote" endpoint is 127.0.0.1.

Comment: But there's problem, the sent SYN should go to itself(already in SYN_SENT state), this corresponds to the simultaneous open.